# How do you use foreign and English phrases together?

Tags: foreign-phrases

Writing in English, if I use a foreign phrase and wish to translate it, what's the standard way to go about it?

In my example below I use a comma:

> "Ces't vrai, it's true!" he enthused.

Is this correct handling? Or is a period or semi colon, or some other punctuation required?

Comment: Is the translation intended as a note for the reader's benefit, or did the character actually say it in both languages? Foreign phrases are often printed in italics, so you could write _"C'est vrai!_ (it's true)," he enthused (if it's a note).

Comment: I know this is a matter of style, but I feel that adding a translation is irretrievably clunky. Either your readership, mon brave, is ready for the foreign words as they are, or if not, omit them.

Comment: Following on from Kate's answer: if it's a direct quote (even if fictional) – ie if the character uses both languages – drop the parenthetical brackets. "_C'est vrai!_ – it's true," he enthused. I wouldn't use two exclamation marks, and feel the initial emotional slip into native tongue would be the stronger exclamation.

Answer (score -2):

I would take the translation out of the quotes.

> "C'est vrai!", *it's true* he enthused.

But I agree with @Michael Harvey, just leave the translation out of it. They can *google* it..